# How to change default mail address for installing apps in windows 8 web store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

Can any one help "How to  change default mail address for access windows store apps in windows 8 web store app". I didn't find any option "Sign in with different user".

Please see the image to understand...(Sorry i don't have points to post image)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0egx.png

Thanks

Satish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open "Settings Charm" -> Click on "Your Account" -> Click on "Change User".

[image]

Comment: Thanks Xyroid... But i didn't have same menu. Please look out  http://postimg.org/image/gcozjod53/

Comment: You will see that after opening store app. The image you show me is of settings of desktop. Open store app & then open setting charm.

Comment: Xyroid, i'm trying same thing and no default user in my store.Check this http://ctrlv.in/241240.   When i click sign in same thing i face  http://ctrlv.in/241238

Comment: Try to remove/change account from PC setting -> Users. PC setting is available in desktop's setting charm. http://postimg.org/image/gcozjod53/

Comment: Hello Xyriod, I solved this problem by changing login account by Microsoft account specifing in pic http://ctrlv.in/241277.  Thanks for your help to find this.

Comment: This is the worst part when after a long try answers don't get accepted :) guess he's offline.